# Graphviz2 in perl to save graph image

Tags: perl, graphics, graph

I would like to output the graph generated by using GraphViz2 perl module to a file. I have the next code, but it doesn't save the image. How can I save it?

```
my $output_dir = "/home/user/Desktop/output.png";

my($graph) = GraphViz2 -> new ();

                (
                 edge   => {color => 'grey'},
                 global => {directed => 1},
                 graph  => {label => 'Adult', rankdir => 'TB'},
                 logger => $logger,
                 node   => {shape => 'oval'},
                );

        $graph -> add_node(name => 'Carnegie', shape => 'circle');
        $graph -> add_node(name => 'Murrumbeena', shape => 'box', color => 'green');
        $graph -> add_node(name => 'Oakleigh',    color => 'blue');

        $graph -> add_edge(from => 'Murrumbeena', to    => 'Carnegie', arrowsize => 2);
        $graph -> add_edge(from => 'Murrumbeena', to    => 'Oakleigh', color => 'brown');





my($format)      = shift || 'png';
my($output_dir) = shift || File::Spec -> catfile('png', "sub.graph.$format");

$graph -> run(format => $format, output_file => $output_file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my($output_dir) = shift || File::Spec -> catfile('png', "sub.graph.$format");
```

should be

```
my($output_file) = shift || File::Spec -> catfile('html', "sub.graph.$format");
```

Your code has no `$output_file` you've made a typo or copied/pasted code incorrectly from somewhere.